# Just want to change url in address bar but backend request will be same?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I am working on a project in MVC5 using c#. I have a requirement of url.
Like as I am hitting a url
`"somesite.com/somepage?userid=1234&folderid=3210"`

I want both ids in my action of controller.

but the problem is I want to display it in address bar like

`somesite.com/Profile/{userid}`
eg: `"somesite.com/Profile/1234".`

as per requirement folder id is not there in displayed url but it is there in request url. and I need this folderid on my action.

I do lot of R&D but didn't get any answer.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried URL Rewriting in IIS ?

Comment: the best way is to store it in session. just remove it after use

Comment: @maku who said you this is best way ?

Comment: based on my opinion, why?

Comment: Beacause sessions are not very good to use unless very neccessary.

Comment: just giving alternatives, i knew it. relax, take a coffee, i just want to help

Comment: OK than i should tell you that you can use URL Rewrite module in IIS which will automatically do this for you.

Comment: Just curious - why do you need this? Does `folderID` have a 1:1 relationship with `userid`? If so, and you don't want it displayed in the address bar, does it even need to be in the request url ever? Why not just associated with the user server-side? And if it is 1:* with `userid` I don't see how rewriting the url helps, you can't afaik *hide* parameters with rewriting unless they are unchanging in which case, why bother having them in the url in the first place.

Comment: it has 1:N relation with folder. yes I tried url rewriting. but it didn't work.
Mairaj: can you give me an example. because I have tried lot of things

Comment: I just don't see why you would want to do this. The Routing system spilt's the url into segments and looks through the routing table in the order the are added to the collection to find the best match. To match Controllers, Actions & Parameters from  url that has missing segemnt values, is never going to work. Ive used re-write modules in Web Forms, but never with MVC.